# How to convert decimal value into US dollar money value in C# while doing Dataconversion?

Tags: c#, currency, data-conversion

I am looking for an option if I could convert the nullable decimal value to currency while I am doing dataconversion in my c# code. I have seen multiple questions about conversion but I am not getting what I am trying to accomplish. I have done follwing so far and it is giving me red underline under `moneyvalue`. When I hover into it, it is complaining saying "can not convert from string to decimal?"

```
decimal? value = DataConversion.GetNullableDecimal(row["Price"]);
string moneyvalue= String.Format("{0:c}", value);

results.Add(new ProductSearchResult(
        product: product,
        msrp: moneyvalue,
        vendornumber: DataConversion.GetString(row["vendor"])
));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: if your "red underline" is under msrp: moneyvalue then just use "value". It seems to me that you should convert later whenever you "show" the search results.

Comment: @IvayloStoev: That gives me decimal result but i need dollar money value. something like $120.90

Comment: You don't need dollar money value if the ProductSearchResult constructor needs a decimal. Either you change the constructor OR you convert later whenever you show the actual value to the user

Comment: @IvayloStoev: Ok. thank you. I didn't know as I am beginner and learning C#. I am displaying its value in markup. So, do I or can I convert it in there? I am displaying it as `<td runat="server"> MSRP:<%=Model.msrp%> </td>`

Comment: Yes. How exactly depends on the framework you are using. You can google this though.

Answer (score 0):

If your msrp is of type **decimal** then:

```
if(value.HasValue){
    results.Add(new ProductSearchResult(
        product: product,
        msrp: value.Value
    ));
}
```

if your msrp is of type **decimal?** then just assing the value:

```
results.Add(new ProductSearchResult(
    product: product,
    msrp: value
));
```

And formatting to $ should be done where you display the value. Your structure **ProductSearchResult** would not accept currency if it requires decimal.

Comment: This may be wrong if you want to always have the product results, even without a value